# Buffering Issue in Vitamio Video Library in Android with WAMP Server

Tags: android, wamp, android-videoview, vitamio

I am trying to play a MP4 video placed in local wamp server using vitamio video library in Android application.

When I am tethering the WAMP server and connecting the android phone to the network and trying to play the video, the video play starts only after the file is completely loaded (i.e) Usually the onPreparedListener will be called as soon a part of MP4 file is downloaded and the remaining will be buffered. But this is not happening the local server.

Whereas, When I am connecting the android app to the Actual Web server, the video buffering is working as expected. Kindly help in this regard.

How to proceed with this situation?

1. Is this problem due to the Android Vitamio Library?
2. Does wamp server needs any setting to support streaming?

Thanks